# "for you to look through it"

Tags: usage

> She gave you her phone to get it charged, not for you to look through it.

Does the sentence above sound fine?

Someone's phone had almost died. When she left to go the restroom, the person who had let her borrow his charger, started going through her phone. And the person who had witnessed this, objected by saying the sentence above. Is there a better way of putting it?

Comment: Sounds like the normal thing to say.

Comment: Why, in particular, are you worried about this sentence?

Comment: A colleague at work was caught out as an adulterer, when, as he said. his wife 'went through' his phone. He was quite indignant that she had stooped to such an action.

Comment: @JamesK because I made this up, and I'm not sure if it sounds natural..... So does it sound fine?

Comment: Look through is fine and normal.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  I guess you must make up lots of English sentences every day.  Something about this one must have made you stop and think..."Hmm I'm not sure if this sounds natural".  Now, why do you have a doubt about this sentence?   "I'm not sure" is not a clarification.  Try to understand what makes you unsure, then you can get a useful answer.